# Are there two different meanings in the sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> She cut plywood with sides of ten cm.

Are there two meanings in this sentence? I mean does it mean that she cut plywood that has sides of 10cm or she wants plywood to have sides of 10cm and cut it accordingly?

Comment: Who knows? One would need further context to understand. There are one or two grammatical mistakes in your question however. I think it should say *Are there two meanings in this sentence? Does it mean that she cut plywood* (non-countable noun, cannot take an indefinite article) *that has sides of 10cm or that she wants plywood with sides of 10cm, and cut accordingly?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, theoretically your sentence could mean either:

> There was plywood that had sides of 10cm and she cut it

or

> She cut plywood so that it had sides of 10cm.

You have to work out which is meant from context. This makes it a poor sentence, and it would be better to write one that removed the ambiguity, for example:

> She cut plywood into pieces that had sides of 10cm.

or

> She cut pieces of plywood that had had sides of 10cm.